# How to make plus and minus toggle works in all the items

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I've made a plus and minus **fieldset** using **bootstrap**, here is the code:

```
<div class="counter-order">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="kale" name="kalkal" class="form-control" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="999" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i placed the code inside a **Jinja** `{% for %}` logic to get it in all the products in case that the client want more than one.

What works here is just the first product in the list, for instance, if i made a 3 of it i get the value like this for example:

**Laptop i5 x3**

but, for the rest products i can't make the amount that i want i get that 3 value .

Am using the `Jquery`.`bind('click')`, here is the code:

```
$('a#process_menu').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('{{url_for("background_process_for_orders")}}', {
          menu_order: $(this).text(), price_order: $('input[name="kalkal"]').val(),
        },
```

also the **html Dom** where the **fieldset** have been placed:

```
<a id="process_menu">
    <div class="hover-text">
        <h4 id="title">{{menu_ent.title}}</h4>
        <small id="price">{{menu_ent.price}}</small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-plus add_basket"></i>
        <div class="counter-order">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="kale" name="kalkal" class="form-control" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="999" />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="../../static/{{menu_ent.path}}" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="image-menu">
</a>
```

even i've tried `document.getElementById('kale').value`, also `$(this).value`, all of it not working at all !, am still getting the first element value for the rest products or the default value which is in my case 1.

How to get that work, any suggestions please :) .

Comment: IDs must be unique in a HTML page as the browser can only return the first match. Use classes instead to avoid that issue. You also wanted `$(this).val()` and not `$(this).value` for jQuery access to values.

Comment: Suggestion: Where you use a templating system to generate multiple items, it is always a good idea to provide the output HTML as well (e.g. as saved from a browser page). This allows a mockup to be made with your multiple items.

Comment: Also: Wrapping your entire form in a an anchor seems "a little odd". What was the intention there

Comment: i know its a little bit odd, but i need to get all the values in a row .

Comment: That does not require an anchor.

Comment: Tell you what... Provide a HTML dump from your browser (with multiple items shown) and I will mockup a working demo in a JSFiddle.

Comment: do you mean a dump for a product with it request and response !

Comment: No, just the HTML of the page, saved from the browser, as requested earlier on :) I should have said HTML output or DOM content.

Comment: here you go, http://pastebin.com/kyQw3U1E

Comment: Wow... you have a lot of cleaning up to do. At least 5 items per section have ID *which cannot be repeated on a page*. Need to make them all classes. I will start putting together a step-by-step answer, but it will take a while

Comment: what an awesom community :), take your time mate i'll wait your answer, i'll clean up the Dom while you finish , thanks alot in advanced ;) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique in a HTML page as the browser can only return the first match.

Use classes instead to avoid that issue. You also wanted `$(this).val()` and not `$(this).value` for jQuery access to values.

### Changes (may require style changes to match):

- `<a id="process_menu">` changed to `<a class="process_menu">`
- `<h4 id="title">` changed to `<h4 class="title">`
- `<small id="price">` changed to `<small class="price">`
- image ids changed from `id="image-menu">` to an extra entry
- `<p id="descr">` to `<p class="descr">`
- Don't wrap your lines inside anchors. You can get a click event from any element. Changed them all to divs to avoid confusing the browser.

Example of changed HTML in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5169mnb5/

The click event on the "row" needs to access the values relative to the element clicked (e.e. `this`). You can use `$(this).find('kalkal')` or you can use `$('.kalkal', this)` which applies the scope to the search.

Also safer/quicker/shorter (as it can minimise) to save the `this` value inside the click event and reference that when needed:

e.g.

```
$('.process_menu').bind('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $.getJSON('{{url_for("background_process_for_orders")}}', {
       menu_order: $this.text(), price_order: $('.kalkal', $this).val(),
    },
```

Comment: i will give it a shoot, really appreciated :) .

Comment: It wooooooooooooooooked, you made my day dude, tell me how to thank you :) .

Comment: @Reznov: When you have enough rep points to upvote, please do so on any useful answers on SO. That keeps the wheels of progress turning :)